# Is there is a end game cut sequence if you fail in the middle of the final mission

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In the Temple_Ship_Assault mission I lost most of my men and then finally The Volunteer died, which ended the game and gave me a game over screen. "Restart mission" or "Exit to Main Mission". Is there a end game cinematics for this losing criteria which I missed which can be triggered some how?

Comment: The Ethereals do mention you failing in the pop-up voices, despite there being no cutscenes (that I know of)

Comment: The spoilers need to be removed; a question must make sense without spoilers to be valid.

Comment: @Frank: Is there a meta discussion to back that up? I see no problem with the idea that a question might only be answerable by those willing to spoiler themselves. Sure, it might mean some people will never read the question and it is useless for them but anybody who has completed the game will probably be fine to look at the spoiler text and answer the question. I mean, the question seems perfectly reasonable. And then the spoilers were hidden. I'm not sure what is objectionable here.

Comment: @Chris https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/of-spoilers-plot-twists-and-our-mission  Essentially, if a question doesn't make sense without spoilers, it shouldn't be in spoilers.

Comment: Happy to remove the spoiler if that makes more sense for the site. But I don't agree at all with the statements in the above posted meta conversation. One of the main argument is about "googleability" which wouldn't be affected by spoilers since it's a pure css and wouldn't hide the text from search engines. The second argument about not working on mobile seems to be debunked by the answers/comments in the tread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You didn't miss anything. References: I tried failing the mission and didn't get anything.